# Linked List in C

Tags: c, linked-list

Although not requirement of my course, I am trying to implement single and double linked list to ensure I understand the concepts. I have worked out most of the issues I think except for one that I have tried to debug and `printf` my way out of.  Although I have read different posts I cannot find out why they are not working similarly.

One my insert function when the `while(h != NULL)` kicks out I have to check the last item one more time because it would skip it. I thought about a do/while loop but that would not work.

I have the exact same loop for the search function and it finds the last item in the list using `while(h != NULL)` instead of kicking me before processing it.

Here is the loop that works from the search function,

```
    while(h != NULL) //check list
        if(h->val == s)
            return true;
        else
           h = h->next;
```

Here is the loop that does not from the insert function, this one does not end up using the final value in the linked list before exiting the loop.  If you read in the full code before I had to check if `if (t->next == NULL && t->val > n)` to get it to search the last item.

```
        while(t->next != NULL) //assigns it in the middle
        {
            if(t->val < n)
                t = t->next;
            else
            {
                node* tt = t->prev; 
                tt->next = a;
                a->next = t;
                a->prev = t->prev;
                t->prev = a;

                return h; //returns original
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance and hopefully I am explaining it. Difficult as I am attempting to learn what I do not know.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h> //for rand();
#include <stdbool.h> //bool function

typedef struct _node
{
    int val;
    struct _node* next;
    struct _node* prev;
} node;

node* create(int n, node* h);

node* insert(int n, node* h);

bool search(int s, node* h);

void print(node* h);

void del(node* h);

int main()
{
    node* h = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        int n = rand() % 15;
        h = create(n, h);
    }

    print(h);

    int s = 10; //number to search for

    if(search(s, h))
        printf("Found Item\n");
    else
        printf("Item not found\n");

    del(h);
}

bool search(int s, node* h)
{
    if(h == NULL)
        printf("No nodes created to search.\n");

    while(h != NULL) //check list
        if(h->val == s)
            return true;
        else
           h = h->next; 

    return false;
}


void del(node* h)
{
    node* t = h;

    while (h->next != NULL)
    {
        t = h->next;
        h->next = NULL;
        free(h);
        h = t;
    }
        free(h);
}

node* insert(int n, node* h)
{
    node* a = malloc(sizeof(node));
    node* t = h;

    if(a == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed to create new node\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    a->val = n; //sets new node to have value of n

    if(h->val >= n) //assigns the integer to the beginning
    {
        a->next = t;
        t->prev = a;
        a->prev = NULL;
        h = a; //assigns a new head since it appended the item to the beginning
        return h;
    }

    while(t->next != NULL) //assigns it in the middle
    {
        if(t->val < n)
            t = t->next;
        else
        {
            node* tt = t->prev; 
            tt->next = a;
            a->next = t;
            a->prev = t->prev;
            t->prev = a;

            return h; //returns original
        }
    }

    if (t->next == NULL && t->val > n) //check to see if second to last  
    {       
        node* tt = t->prev;
        tt->next = a;
        a->next = t;
        a->prev = t->prev;
        t->prev = a;
    }
    else
    {
        a->next = NULL;
        a->prev = t;
        t->next = a;
    }

    return h;
}

node* create(int n, node* h)
{
    if(h == NULL) //create first node in the list
    {
        h = malloc(sizeof(node));
        if(h == NULL)
        {
            printf("Failed to create first node\n");
            return NULL;
        }
        h->val = n;
        h->next = NULL;
        h->prev = NULL;
    }
    else //create additional nodes in the list
        h = insert(n, h);

    return h;
}

void print(node* h)
{
    if(h == NULL)
        printf("List is empty\n");
    else
        while(h != NULL)
        {
            printf("%i\n", h->val);
            h = h->next;
        }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry for not being clear, it is Harvard's online class through edx.org you can do for free.  They cover linked lists and doubles but it is not required to submit as an assignment.

Comment: "my insert function when the while(h != NULL) kicks out". There is no such condition in your `insert` function. Can you please clarify?

Comment: @kaylum the condition is inside `void print(node* h)` function.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/HC1DLK4M

Comment: @Marievi OP specifically says the insert function. You could be right that OP actually means the `print` function. But would be good for OP to clarify personally and fix up the question.

Comment: it is in the insert function sorry, the exact code is in this loop while(t->next != NULL).  It does not compare the last item.  Yet in the search function the same loop uses the last item.

Comment: Please add the "expected" and "actual" behaviour into the question itself.

Comment: @JDL But we've just established that `search` and `insert` are *not* using the same condition. One checks the node pointer whilst the other checks the next pointer. Why do you say they are "the exact same loop"?

Comment: The second loop checks `t->next != null` where the first loop just checks `h != null`. That's why the second loop stops _before_ the end of the list.

Comment: And now that you say that, it is so bluntly obvious I feel stupid for asking. Now to redesign the loop to not need so many parts, although it works, it seems sloppy.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: [CS50 Library](https://manual.cs50.net/library/)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about these lines:

```
while(t->next != NULL) //assigns it in the middle
{
    if(t->val < n)
        t = t->next;
    else
    {
        node* tt = t->prev; 
        tt->next = a;
        a->next = t;
        a->prev = t->prev;
        t->prev = a;

        return h; //returns original
    }
}

if (t->next == NULL && t->val > n) //check to see if second to last  
{       
    node* tt = t->prev;
    tt->next = a;
    a->next = t;
    a->prev = t->prev;
    t->prev = a;
}
else
{
    a->next = NULL;
    a->prev = t;
    t->next = a;
}
```

and the question is: "How can to avoid repeating the code block from inside the while after the while"

Maybe something like this:

```
while(1) 
{
    if(t->val < n)
    {
        if (t->next == NULL) break;
        t = t->next;
    } 
    else
    {
        //assigns it in the middle
        node* tt = t->prev; 
        tt->next = a;
        a->next = t;
        a->prev = t->prev;
        t->prev = a;

        return h; //returns original
    }
}

// Add new node at the end
a->next = NULL;
a->prev = t;
t->next = a;
```